# Drawing dashed and continuous lines

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, line, cgcontext

I need to draw lines; some are dashed and others are continuous. I cannot know which are dashed and which are not. When I draw the dashed lines, I use this:

```
CGContextSetLineDash(context, 5, linedashPattern, 2); // set dashed line
```

It happens, however, that if I draw a dotted line the next ones are also all dashed. Is there an operation to reset the "Dashed" state, to draw a continuous line?
For example:

```
CGContextSetLineContinuous(context,......); // set continuous line
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0, NULL, 0);
```

B.t.w. I can only recommend to check the documentation. Definitely faster than posting a question on SO ;)

Comment: I m getting EXE_BAD_ACCESS if I set NULL as per your description.

Comment: @DivineDesert no your EXE_BAD_ACCESS come through some other line. Here NULL argument means your line **no dash pattern** ,that means your output should be solid line if we set NULL . See documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetLineDash.

Comment: FYI I was getting the same EXE_BAD_ACCESS and it was because I was using 1's and not zeros, as in: CGContextSetLineDash(ctx, 1, NULL, 1);  So be careful to use the line exactly as shown by Nikolai.